# Can not click on the Menu under this video pop up

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, menu

Whenever I want to click on the menu. The video pop up appears and this pop up we cannot close due to this I can not click the menu under this pop-up. IDE shows the following error. You can also see the screenshot attached.

Please suggest some answers to this problem.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <a href="...Input.php">Deposit</a> is not clickable at point (120, 268). Other element would receive the click: <div>...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.39.562718 (9a2698cba08cf5a471a29d30c8b3e12becabb0e9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19041 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 2):

Selenium will only interact with Elements a user would be able to interact with. The first question would be if your users have the same issue when trying to click the element you want to interact with, if they do handling the video should probably be part of your test flow. If it doesn't happen when you interact with the application manually try to reverse engineer why your automation triggers this behavior.

If you just want to click the element, disregarding the actual user's workflow (which I wouldn't recommend, though I'm aware that this might sometimes be necessary) you can just use seleniums Javascript Executor.

In java that would just be  `((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", yourWebElement);` which will circumvent Seleniums restrictions regarding actions not performable by the user.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the element is not yet clickable. In that case, you should first wait for the element to be clickable using waits and ExpectedConditions:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)).click();
```

(this is Java implementation since you didn't specify which language you are using, but it is similar in other languages).

Another common case is that the element is clickable but there is an overlay over it. You can use the following to wait until the overlay disappears:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(overlay-element)).click();
```